# Redux - ES6 Updating Object Element in Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I have stumbled upon a problem when adding an element inside an object inside an array. What I would like to do is add the element `isFavorite: true`. I am currently attempting to do so by doing the folowing:

```
{ 
    ...state, 
    list: state.list.map(item => 
        item.id === action.payload.libraryContentId ? 
        { ...item, isFavorite: true } 
        : item) 
}
```

The payload contains the following object:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Name',
    libraryContentId: 3
}
```

But the above does not seem to be updating the item and add the element. What do you guys suggest?

**Edit**: More examples of the code.

Action:

```
try {
    const response = await axios.post(URL, {params});
    dispatch({ type: ADD_FAVORITE, payload: response.data });
catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: ERROR });
}
```

Response Data:

```
{
    id: 117
    libraryConntentId: 245
}
```

List item sample:

```
{
    id: 245,
    name: 'Name',
    isFavorite: false
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does it make a difference if you add `()` around your overwriting statement? Like so `({ ...item, isFavorite: true })`

Comment: If the state isn't updated I also suggest you provide more code since the problem might be elsewhere than your new state object.

Comment: What you have written looks reasonable. Could you include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? There might be something else going on, like e.g. the id is a string in your state, etc.

Comment: @E.Sundin I tried your suggestion and it still won't update the state. I am trying to see where the problem may lay since the condition is being met through the iteration meaning the action is properly dispatching the payload.

Comment: @Tholle Hi Tholle, I have gone ahead and added a few examples of the objects and the action making the dispatch. The expression `item.id === action.payload.libraryContentId` does return the correct item when I log it to the console. Is there anything else that you see?

Comment: Your response data seems to have a typo in it, `libraryContnetId`. Maybe you can extract all relevant minimal code and put it in a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)?

Comment: @Tholle Yes sorry that was a typo on my end when writing the Edit. The data is returned correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this (check testMethod):

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
   super(props);
    
    
    let testData = [
     {
       id: 1,
        name: 'Name1',
        isFavorite: false
      },
      {
       id: 2,
        name: 'Name2',
        isFavorite: false
      },
      {
       id: 3,
        name: 'Name3',
        isFavorite: false
      },
      {
       id: 4,
        name: 'Name4',
        isFavorite: false
      },
      {
       id: 5,
        name: 'Name5',
        isFavorite: false
      }]
    
    this.state = {
     boolvar: true,
        numbar: 2,
     list: testData
    }
    this.testMethod = this.testMethod.bind(this);
    console.log("Original state");
    console.log(this.state);
  }
  
  testMethod(){
     let testAction = {
  payload: {
     libraryContentId: 3
     }
 }
  
   this.setState((prevState, prevProps) => {
      return {
       list: [...prevState.list.map(item => item.id === testAction.payload.libraryContentId? {...item, isFavorite: true}: item)]
       }});
   }
  render(){
   console.log(this.state);
    return (<div><button onClick={() => {this.testMethod()}}>Test It</button></div>);
  }
  
   
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```